# Load a Codeigniter view with Jquery Popup

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I Want to load my view with Jquery Pop up. I did it with normal browser popup with Jquery.

```
$("#btn_preview").click(function(e){
        var message=$('#txtMessageRequired').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {message: message},
            url: base_url+'index.php/newsletter/preview_newsletter',//Important: base_url is defined in the header section
            success:function(result){
                var w = window.open('about:blank', 'Newsletter Preview');
                w.document.write(result);
                w.document.close();

            }
        });
    });
```

But tried a lot to do it with Jquery pop up.

Is there any solution.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: just create a normal jquery ui normal popup, then open it up inside the success block

Comment: I think this is going to help you
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/loading-codeigniter-views-in-a-dialog
For jquery dialog 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i could solve my problem..

```
$("#btn_preview").click(function(){
        var name=$('#txtName').val();
        var message=$('#txtMessageRequired').val();
        var tag = $("<div></div>");
        $(tag).attr("title", "Preview - Newsletter");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {message: message, name: name},
            url: base_url+'index.php/newsletter/preview_newsletter',//Important: base_url is defined in the header section
            success:function(result){
                $(tag).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    show: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 1000
                    },
                    hide: {
                        effect: "explode",
                        duration: 1000
                    }
                });
                $(tag).dialog( "option", "width", 670 );
                $(tag).html(result).dialog().dialog('open');
            }
        });
    });
```